# How do I AddAddress automatically in PHPmailer from form php info?

Tags: email, phpmailer

This has got to be a simple one, but I've been searching all over and nothing seems relevant to my problem: or i'm not able to interpret advice for others adequately.

I'm getting the error "You must provide at least one recipient email address. Message could not be sent."

If I put a specific email address in 'AddAddress' field the message is sent. I want to have an email sent to the user who has submitted their form as an automatic email response thanking user for registering... Thus the ($_POST['email']) in the 'AddAddress' field. This works in Mail() php function. Why not PHP MAiler? What am I missing?

Here is my code with sensitive bits taken out (Relevant bit - I think - in bold):

```
        <?php    
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(email,) VALUES('$email',)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = ""; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "";
$mail->FromName = "";
**$mail->AddAddress = ($_POST['email']);**

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "";
$mail->Body    = "";
$mail->AltBody = "";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Many thanks in advance for your advice. Hopefully this will help others too...

Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple one... just change this line

```
$mail->AddAddress = ($_POST['email']);
```

to this:

```
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
```

as it is a **method**, as opposed to a **variable**, on the class!  :)

there are some good examples you can use on the [PHPMailer GitHub](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.  That link is to the most recent (ie. maintained) version of PHPMailer!  Loads of good stuff over there